# Enable users to edit link rots

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, link-rot

An answer to previous [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263398/routine-inspection-of-internet-links?noredirect=1#comment857055_263398) on link rots indicated that they are best fixed by user edits. Such edits are limited to a minimum of 6 characters, which is sometimes not the case with link rots. So how should they be fixed?

Comment: oops... almost ashamed to find this one is also a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

Is the rest of the post so perfect that you cannot find six characters of edit?

In most cases, most people could use the link rot as a trigger for an edit and then improve the rest of the post a little.

I suspect there are many link-rotted posts that could also do with tidying up, even if only removal of "*Thanks in advance*" or similar.

Comment: Sometimes the fix is a small change. Either a path changed or someone missed ["www"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300916/i-estimate-10-of-the-links-posted-here-are-dead-how-do-we-deal-with-them/302100#comment229947_300916)

Comment: Usually you can find some way to please the character counter, but it is a pain… It seems "obvious" that edits to links can be highly significant without needing to be more than a character (e.g., a missing dot). It is a drag to have to figure out some other appropriate edit to get around the character counter. Can this be fixed?